# Assign a value from a vertical range in ascending order to another cell first time a criteria is met then exit

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly at all but I'm trying to write a subroutine that looks for the first value that meets my criteria, then copies it to another cell, then stops looking for any more values.

To be explicit, I have a column of 18 months in ascending order (oldest to newest) and I'm comparing it to today's date.

- Sep 1st, 2019
- Oct 1st, 2019
- Nov 1st, 2019
- Dec 1st, 2019
- Jan 1st, 2020
- Feb 1st, 2020
- Mar 1st, 2020
- Apr 1st, 2020
- May 1st, 2020
- Jun 1st, 2020
- Jul 1st, 2020
- Aug 1st, 2020
- Sep 1st, 2020
- Oct 1st, 2020
- Nov 1st, 2020
- Dec 1st, 2020
- Jan 1st, 2021
- Feb 1st, 2021

I then want the first month that is after today's date to be copied over to another cell, and then for the Macro to stop searching for more values that meet this criteria.

This is what my code looks like right now.

```
Sub Show_remaining_months()

        Dim TodaysDate As Long 'Today's Value
        
        Dim MonthCell As Range
        Dim i As Byte
        Dim EndHere As Byte
        
        
        Dim RestoreRefStyle As Integer
        Let RestoreRefStyle = Application.ReferenceStyle
        
        
        Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
        
        
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("subtotalizer(r-hrs)").Activate
        
        Let TodaysDate = Worksheets("subtotalizer(r-hrs)").Range("R1C5").Value ' TodaysDate = 44012
        
        
                    
                    
                    
                Let EndHere = 23
                                                     'Range(R6C3:R23C3)
                                For Each MonthCell In Range("R6C3:R" & (EndHere) & C3)
                                        
                                        For i = 6 To EndHere ' For i = 6 To 23
                                                             ' Which later then becomes i To EndHere.
                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                   If MonthCell.Value < TodaysDate Then
                                                   'Skip
                                                   i = i + 1
                                                   'i = 6 + 1 = 7
                                                   
                                                   Else
                                                   Let Range(R3C5).Value = MonthCell.Value
                                                   'i = i + 1
                                                   EndHere = i
                                                   
                                                   End If
                                                                                                 
                                       Next i
                                
                                Next MonthCell
 
    
        Application.ReferenceStyle = RestoreRefStyle


End Sub
```

**I get Error Code 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error**

To be honest, I think I'm overthinking this one. I'm new to VBA programming.

Answer (score 0):

This re-write does exactly what I wanted. I was overthinking it.

```
Sub Show_remaining_months()


    Dim TodaysDate As Long 'Today's Value
    Dim StartDate As Range
            
    Dim MonthCell As Range
    Dim i As Byte
    Dim EndHere As Byte
        

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("subtotalizer(r-hrs)").Activate
        
        Let TodaysDate = Range("E1").Value
        Set CurrentStartDate = Range("E3")
        

              For Each MonthCell In Range("C6:C23")
                                        
                         If MonthCell.Value > TodaysDate Then
                            CurrentStartDate.Value = MonthCell.Value
                                    
                            Exit Sub
                                                 
                         End If
            
              Next MonthCell
 
End Sub
```